# Сообщения в ФБ с помощью бота

Tags: facebook

Добрый день! Может кто сталкивался с таким. При пользовании бота в ФБ и отправке сообщений с кнопками, юзеру не приходят кнопки, только сообщения. И это только у некоторых юзеров. Количество кнопок и их длина нормальная. Одно и то же сообщение с кнопкой у большинства приходит, но есть юзеры, у которых не отображаются кнопки в сообщении. Не знаю куда писать. Помогите пожалуйста! С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Возможно из-за версий клиентов если речь идет о мобильном приложении.

Comment: Я тоже так предполагал, но ничего не нашел в инете. А нужно точно знать, так как клиенты негодуют ((((

Comment: В самой API разве не написано с какой версии появились эти кнопки? Обычно такое пишут в `changelogs` или в самом описании метода где они используются.

Comment: Не находил в описании такой инфы, что зависит что-то от версии ПО телефона.

Comment: Телефон тут не при чем, я про версию клиента ФБ самого.